# Automator AppleScript: Only Click Checkbox if Unchecked

Tags: applescript, automator

I'm creating an Automator workflow to click the Enable This Account checkbox in the Contacts preferences pane. I used Watch Me Work in Automator to make most of it easy. The automation runs fine, but I want to add code to only check the box if it's unchecked. I searched a similar question, but the code in the example isn't structured anything like the code I'm seeing in Automator. I'm a very beginner programmer, so any help would be much appreciated.

```
on run {input, parameters}
-- Click the “Enable this account” checkbox.
delay 0.441495
set timeoutSeconds to 2.000000
set uiScript to "click checkbox \"Enable this account\" of tab group 1 of group 1 of group 1 of window \"Accounts\" of application process \"Contacts\""
my doWithTimeout( uiScript, timeoutSeconds )
return input
end run

on doWithTimeout(uiScript, timeoutSeconds)
    set endDate to (current date) + timeoutSeconds
    repeat
        try
            run script "tell application \"System Events\"
" & uiScript & "
end tell"
            exit repeat
        on error errorMessage
            if ((current date) > endDate) then
                error "Can not " & uiScript
            end if
        end try
    end repeat
end doWithTimeout
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following *example* **AppleScript** *code* assumes there is only one account in **Contacts** > **Preferences…** > **Accounts** and will only click the **Enable this account** *checkbox* if it's *not checked*, and then closes the preferences *window*:

<sub>**Note:**  The *example* **AppleScript** *code* was tested under **macOS High Sierra** and may need to be modified for *earlier/later* versions of **macOS**.</sub>

```applescript
tell application "Contacts" to activate
tell application "System Events"
    repeat while not (exists window 1 of application process "Contacts")
        delay 0.1
    end repeat
    tell application process "Contacts"
        click menu item "Preferences…" of menu 1 of menu bar item "Contacts" of menu bar 1
        repeat until (exists button "Accounts" of toolbar 1 of window 1)
            delay 0.1
        end repeat
        click button "Accounts" of toolbar 1 of window 1
        repeat while not (exists checkbox "Enable this account" of tab group 1 of group 1 of group 1 of window 1)
            delay 0.1
        end repeat
        if not (value of checkbox "Enable this account" of tab group 1 of group 1 of group 1 of window 1 as boolean) then
            click checkbox "Enable this account" of tab group 1 of group 1 of group 1 of window 1
        end if
        keystroke "w" using command down
    end tell
end tell
```

Comment: Thank you! That's so much better than what I was doing. And I learned a few important things from the code. Appreciate it! BTW... I edited the keystroke at the end to Q to quit the app instead of close the preferences window.